# How to Prevent FQDN when using React Router with hashHistory

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When using the [*hashHistory*](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#hashhistory) approach with react-router and clicking on a
`<Link to="/admin">Admin Screen</Link>`, I see this in my browser's address bar:  `http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/#/http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/admin?_k=emdg1n`

I was expecting: `http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/#/admin?_k=emdg1n`

Oddly, I do end up at the Admin Screen visually but also I receive this error in my console:

```
Warning: [react-router] Location "/http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/admin" did not match any routes
```

When I use the *browserHistory* method I do not see any problems.

I'm hoping I'm missing somethings easy -- note that my app is not at the root of the web server, so my routes are configured like this currently:

```
<Route path='/path/to/app/' component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    <Route path="/admin" component={Admin}/>
</Route>
```

EDIT:
<strike>I just can't seem to track down why the absolute/fully-qualified domain name is showing up in the route.</strike>  It appears this has to do with having `<base href="http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/">` in my HTML source.  I think the conflict might be with the *[history](https://github.com/mjackson/history)* library that is used by *react-router*.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <base href="http://localhost:8080/path/to/app/">
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id="root"></span>
        <script src="includes/scripts/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: It appears this behavior is coming from my use (or misuse) of the <base href=""> tag in my HTML source.  Not sure yet how to proceed but I updated the question with my HTML source.

Comment: I _think_ this might be getting solved in https://github.com/mjackson/history/issues/94